# Calculate the speed of a moving object given the time at which it reaches its destination

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An object is at location `(x,y)`.
The time in milliseconds now is `n`.
The time at which the object should be at location `(a,b)` is `t`.

How would one go about calculating the speed at which the object needs to move?

I have tried the following but the speed seems to increase all the time (as the difference between the end time and now becomes smaller).

```
distance_x = (destination_x - current_x) / end_time - now
```

The units are arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

The basic equation is $distance=speed \times time$. Dividing both sides by $time$ gives us

$$speed=\frac{distance}{time}$$

The distance between the two-dimensional points $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ is, by the Pythagorean theorem, $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$. The time is $t-n$ milliseconds. Substituting those in, and converting the milliseconds to seconds, gives us

$$speed=1000\times\frac{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}{t-n}$$

The unit of speed will be the unit of distance per second. If you want it per millisecond, remove the $1000$ from the equation.

Comment: Actually, it should be $\frac{\Delta \text{distance}}{\Delta\text{time}}$, but $+1$ for the rest of the explanation.

Comment: @JohnJoy: It would be $\left|\frac{\Delta position}{\Delta time}\right|$ or $\frac{distance}{\Delta time}$, but I was keeping things simple.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, thanks. I +1'd it but I can't actually accept the answer because the asking account isn't linked to my SE profile for some reason.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I guess my point was that "keeping things simple" may have consequences for weaker students, later on, when they take Calculus (usually in grade 12), specifically the confusion that they experience in trying to understanding the difference between average velocity and instantaneous velocity.